# Gam.check() and k number

Tags: mgcv

Hello I have a question regarding gam.check()
I understand that small p-values in the output of gam.check() indicate that residuals are not randomly distributed. This often means there are not enough basis functions. However, If I try to increase the basis functions I get the following error :
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :    A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom

From reading on this error the solution is to reduce the k value. 
So my question is: Is it ok to leave the k number as high as it can be so I can run the model without getting the error above, even if the gam.check() function suggest I have to increase the number.

Comment: You seem to be misreading the error message: it is telling you that you requested *too many* knots, not too few.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The error is telling me I requested too many, I agree. What I am unsure of is the small p value on the output of the gam.check() According to function documentation: Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.  Thank you for your time!